# Can Muslims go to war against a secular government for refusing refugees?

Tags: practical-islam, war, government

Does Islam support Muslims, in a secular country, to go against their government if the government does not allow Muslim refugees (Not for religion reason but for some bureaucratic reasons)?

Comment: Islam doesn't support a secular kind of state.

Comment: Is the question about “war” (which might involve killing people) or simply “going against” (which might involve protesting)?

Comment: @Medi1Saif: Nevertheless muslims do live in secular societies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40) the authority of Abu Sa`eed al-Khudree (may Allah be pleased with him) who said:

> I heard the Messenger of Allah (pbuh) say, “Whosoever of you sees an evil, let him change it with his hand; and if he is not able to do so, then [let him change it] with his tongue; and if he is not able to do so, then with his heart — and that is the weakest of faith.” (Hadith 34).

As a citizen of a democratic secular state there are allowed avenues of protest - voting out a government, writing to senators, MPs, charities or NGOs, or going on rallies, public meetings and marches - so these are protests of the 'tongue'; citizens who feel more strongly can engage in civil disobedience, and these are generally outside of the law and hence judged by the courts - so these are protests of the 'hand'.

Take for example the history of the [Dakota Access Pipeline Protests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakota_Access_Pipeline_protests) as a very recent example where one can say all three possibilities were explored: by hand, by tongue & by heart.

Comment: Out of context Hadith. Protests and rebellion is a forbidden act in Islam. Muslims have to accept the decree of the ruler of the nation. He can advise the ruler/Minister in private if he has communication channels. Just because a country allows you to protest and vote, these acts don't become halal for a Muslim.

Comment: @Riyaz: You are being ridiculous. Protests and rebellion is enjoined upon in the Qu'ran as one should "raise one's hand" against "opression". What you are referring to is a theory of kingship in Islam that you seem to know very little about other than the simplest and grossest of cliches.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely Not, they can influence the policymaker or authority by writing, peaceful demonstration and be participating in election etc.
Muslims are also not allowed to go against a Muslim state or just rulers

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you define "war" on your question. But there a sahih hadith told by Tirmidzi, that moslem can criticize the despotic, tyrant or *zalim* goverment in a country.

```
إِنَّ مِنْ أَعْظَمِ الْجِهَادِ كَلِمَةُ عَدْلٍ عِنْدَ سُلْطَانٍ جَائِر
```

This hadith has a shaih (*hasan*) grade. You can look it up from https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/33/17